# PyCharm после установки Pytest не работает автодополнение кода

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

При работе  c `webdriver`  часто приходится обращаться к различным методам, но не всегда знаешь что лучше использовать, и здесь помогает автодополнение. Но после установки `pytest` оно не работает. Может кто знает как это можно решить?

Comment: Скорее всего вообще никак не связано с установкой pytest. Проверьте, что в Pycharm не включен экономный режим (не стоит галка в меню File - Power Save Mode)

Comment: в том-то и дело что не стоит, я уже это проверял